# Get AUTO_INCREMENT of Last Inputted Row

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I have a simple question.

I'm putting info into a MySQL with PHP and I have an auto_increment field that I'm leaving alone.

How do I get the value of the auto_increment field in the row I just entered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(that_field) AS last_auto_increment_value FROM that_table;
```

OR

```
SELECT auto_increment -1 AS last_auto_increment_value
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name='that_table'
AND table_schema = 'that_database';
```

OR

```
mysql_insert_id() //in PHP
```

Comment: Why should you use these elaborate queries instead of mysql_insert_id or the PDO equivalent?

Comment: `SELECT MAX()` would return the largest value which may or may not be the one from the last insert ran.  With `mysql_insert_id()` it will return the id created from the `INSERT` since it's on the same connection instance

Comment: @AaronW. I considered only calling that right after an insert, as I wrote before, I didn't read the question very carefully, didn't even notice the PHP tag. I added the mysql_insert_id function afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

mysql_insert_id()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

From [php.net/mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id)

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's three different approaches, from three commonly used libraries that can interface with MySQL (mysql, mysqli, pdo)

[`mysql_insert_id(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) [procedural function]

[`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) [OOP property]

[`PDO::lastInsertId(...)`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) [OOP method]

Answer (score 1):

PDO::lastInsertId — Returns the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value

[`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)